# $\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan{n}}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

It is right that $\nexists \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan{n}}$ when $x\leq -e$?

For me $$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^n+\arctan{n}}=\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{x^n}{e^n}$$
Then if $x=-e$ I have $\lim_{n\to \infty} (-1)^n$ and this does not exist. In case $x<-e$?

Comment: What have you tried? Read [this](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question) for better answers and to avoid close votes.

Comment: Yes sorry I have edited the question with my idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case that $x<-e$, we have $\frac xe<-1$. Consider the even and odd subsequences. We have
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac xe\right)^{2n}=\infty\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x}{e}\right)^{2n+1}=-\infty$$
Therefore, limit doesn't exist for the given sequence.

Comment: Ok thanks! Can be seen in this following way? In case $x<-e$ i can rewrite $x^n/e^n$ as $(-1)^n|x|^n/e^n$ with $|x|^n/e^n$ increasing right?

Comment: Yes @Sisi, it can be seen in that way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!!

Comment: @Sisi The standard way to thank people on this site is to upvote their answer and accept it if it solves the problem.

Comment: Yes I am going to accept...but the system told me that i had to wait one minute! I try again!